# swift: check records in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

is there a way to check core data from Xcode?

I have created two functions(write into DB, read from DB) which don't fail but read returns empty array when it is supposed to return written data.

Functions:

```
func writeData () {
        appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    context = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let newRecord = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CountryList", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        let timestamp = NSDate()

        for geo in geoArray {

        //geoArray - array of dictionaries ([CountryName: "Lithuania", TelCode: 370],[CountryName: "Belarus", TelCode: 375],[CountryName: "Latvia", TelCode: 371])             
        //geo - Dictionary of tipe <String: AnyObject>
        // CoreData: countryName type is String

        newRecord.setValue(timestamp, forKey: "dateUploaded")
        newRecord.setValue(String(geo["CountryName"]!), forKey: "countryName")

            do {
                try context.save()
                print("Saved successfully")
            } catch _ {
                print("there was issue saving data!")
            }  

          }


        } 







  func loadData(country: String) {
        appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        context = appDel.managedObjectContext


        results = [AnyObject]()

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CountryList")
        request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType

        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "countryName = %@", country)



        let sort1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateUploaded", ascending: true)

        request.sortDescriptors = [sort1]

        do {
            results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
            print(results!)

        } catch _ {
            print ("error trying to fetch!")
        }
    }
```

I would like to check from Xcode if there are any records in my CoreData entity. Is that possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually changing the same core data object inside the loop. So ultimately at the end of the loop you will be left with only one object with the last country name in the array. You should create a `newRecord` inside the loop every time instead.

Move this line inside the for loop and it should work fine.

`let newRecord = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CountryList", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject`

Note that you are creating a core data managed object and changing it inside the loop and saving saves the same object multiple times. If you want to save multiple objects you have to create a new object every time, set its values and then save. You an also move the saving part outside the loop.

```
func writeData () {
    let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let timestamp = NSDate()
    for geo in geoArray {
        let newRecord = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CountryList", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        newRecord.setValue(timestamp, forKey: "dateUploaded")
        newRecord.setValue(String(geo["CountryName"]!), forKey: "countryName")
    }
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Saved successfully")
    } catch _ {
        print("there was issue saving data!")
    }

}
```

Comment: that is what i am trying to do - to check if writing works well :) I thought there should be a way to check records in CD from xcode

Comment: Probably not a good way but what we sometimes do is to log the persistent store path and then open that window in Finder and see if the required CoreData files gets created after writing. Of course this works only in Simulator but for testing this is good enough. You can see if the DB is being written properly. A crude way to find out if the DB is being written property. You could also check in the code itself to see if the files are there and have a size greater than zero. Could you add the code that you have for writing and reading from DB?

Comment: Yes this would work for me. My code is in the question . Please check! Can you advise where to look and what files should be created? Thanks

Comment: I put your code in a sample CoreData based application and it write and reads the data properly. How are you calling `loadData` and what parameter are you passing to this function? In your code you are writing just one country `Lithuania` without passing the country but in the loadData you are passing a country name as arg. Could there be a mismatch in what you have written and what you are trying to read?

Comment: That is strange. Yes in my example I insert constant value "Lithuania". And you are right - it is working with it. In real project there is an array of countries with type String:AnyObject. I am looping it and inserting all countries. I see that that element has NSTaggedPointerString type while in Core Data this column is String. Adding conversion to string String(array["CountryName"]) doesn't help ...

Comment: Can you specify the code used to add the countries to Core Data? If the array is of dictionary type then you should be reading the specific key that contains the country name in each element of the array. From your comment it looks like you are indexing the array using CountryName as the key instead of `array[index]["CountryName"]` where index is `0..<n`

Comment: Please check - I have updated my question. Not sure I need to use index in my case. But still not clear why it is not working.

Comment: so the issue is that I am declaring my variable outside the loop ? is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107100/discussion-between-pradeep-k-and-almazini).

Comment: it works after  I have put variable declaration inside the array. thank you